# CouchDB Find One not working

Tags: couchdb

I am a couchDB newbie and am doing the examples in the O'Reilly CouchDB guide.

I have a problem using a view to retrieve a document by key:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/basic/_design/example/_view/by_date?key="2009/01/15 15:52:20"
```

gives the reply:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

but just retrieving all rows:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/basic/_design/example/_view/by_date
```

gives me 3 rows including the specific row I am looking for:

{"id":"hello-world","key":"2009/01/15 15:52:20","value":"Hello World"}

why doesn't the key query work?

I am using CouchDB version 0.10.0 on Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 9):

CouchDB expects the `start_key` parameter to be a valid JSON-compatible type, such as `"a string"` or `12345` or `["an", "array", "with", 5.0, "elements"]`. If you check your CouchDB logs you will probably see a `400` (bad client request) entry because your key is either invalid UTF8 or invalid JSON.

You probably have two problems:

1. The shell is interpreting your quotes which must actually be sent to CouchDB. Try single-quoting your double-quote string.
2. You probably also need to encode your key so that it is a valid URL. Specifically, replace your space with `%20`

Putting this all together, the following works for me on CouchDB 0.11 on Ubuntu 9.10.

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/blog/_design/docs/_view/by_date?key='"2009/01/30%2018:04:11"'
{"total_rows":1,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"biking","key":"2009/01/30 18:04:11","value":"Biking"}
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked, I single-quoted the key string and encoded the space character so the request became:

```
/by_date?key='"2009/01/30%2015:52:20"'
```